# reverse-depends: looking for reverse dependencies of source packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

My goal is finding ALL reverse-depends of a certain package and the belonging source package. For example, I want all packages that depend on `libsslcommon2` and the source package that can be installed via `sudo apt-get source libsslcommon2`.

From the [reverse-depends man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/reverse-depends.1.html) I understand that I need to:

```
sudo reverse-depends `libsslcommon2`
```

which works fine. However

```
sudo reverse-depends src:libsslcommon2
```

returns

```
reverse-depends: Error: Unknown package
```

The same syntax works for `src:bash` though (as mentioned in the man page).

NB: It works well to install/download the sources for both bash and libsslcommon2 via

```
sudo apt-get source libsslcommon2
sudo apt-get source bash
```

What is the problem here? How can I determine all packages that depend on the libsslcommon source package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***TL;DR:*** You can use `reverse-depends src:$(what-source libsslcommon2)`.

There is no `libsslcommon2` source package. Instead, `libsslcommon2` is one of a number of binary packages built from [the `qpid-cpp` source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qpid-cpp). In general, a binary package may or may not have the same name as the source package used to build it, and source packages may provide multiple binary packages.

The name of the source package for [`bash`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bash&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) is also [`bash`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash), but source package names cannot always be guessed from binary package names.

Two of the ways to check what source package is used to build a binary package are:

1. Search for the binary package name under "Packages" at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu.
2. Use the [`what-source`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/what-source.1.html) command. (You must install [what-utils](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/what-utils) [image: Install what-utils] first. To do that from the command line, run `sudo apt-get install what-utils`.) For example, `what-source libsslcommon2` outputs `qpid-cpp`.

In practice I usually use Launchpad because it often has other handy information I'm looking for at the same time. But with `what-source` and `reverse-depends`, you can write a single command to list the reverse dependencies associated with the source package for a particular binary package:

```
reverse-depends src:$(what-source libsslcommon2)
```

This uses [command substitution](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)--a `$(` `)` expression is replaced by the output of the command written inside the parentheses.

You may be surprised at the output of that command, which, at least when run from my 15.04 system, is:

```
No reverse dependencies found
```

But really this is not so surprising. It means no binary packages except those built from the `qpid-cpp` source package depend on any binary packages built from the `qpid-cpp` source package. For example:

```
ek@Io:~$ reverse-depends libsslcommon2
Reverse-Depends
===============
* libsslcommon2-dev
* qpid-client
* qpidd

Packages without architectures listed are reverse-dependencies in: amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
ek@Io:~$ what-source libsslcommon2-dev
qpid-cpp
ek@Io:~$ what-source qpid-client
qpid-cpp
ek@Io:~$ what-source qpidd
qpid-cpp
```

Finally, take note:

- You do *not* need to run `reverse-depends` (nor `what-source`) [as root](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo). That is, `sudo reverse-depends ...` is unnecessary; run `reverse-depends ...` instead.
- As far as the `reverse-depends` utility is concerned, a source package's reverse dependencies are the reverse dependencies of the binary packages that are built from the source package. The specific binary package they depend on is listed in parentheses to the right of the package name, in the output of `reverse-depends src:...`.

  The reverse dependencies of a source package, as listed by `reverse-depends`, *are still binary packages, not source packages.* For example, the output of `reverse-depends src:bash` includes:

  ```
  * netscript-2.4                 (for bash)
  * netscript-2.4-upstart         (for bash)
  ```

  This is even though there is no `netscript-2.4-upstart` *source* package. Instead, the [`netscript-2.4` and `netscript-2.4-upstart` binary packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=netscript-2.4&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) are both built from the [`netscript-2.4` source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netscript-2.4).
- The reverse dependencies of a source package are not the same as the reverse build dependencies of a package. The reverse build dependencies of a package are the other packages that require the package in order to be built, but not necessarily to be installed once built. If you're looking for reverse build dependencies, invoke `reverse-depends` with the `-b` flag.

Comment: First of all: Thanks for your great reply!
Regarding the sudo: I added it because I got the following error without sudo:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/reverse-depends", line 20, in <module>
    from distro_info import DistroDataOutdated
ImportError: No module named distro_info`

Comment: @stackoverflowwww Hmm... Does reinstalling `ubuntu-dev-tools` with `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install ubuntu-dev-tools` fix that?

Comment: No, it did not, unfortunately.

Comment: another strange observation: `what-source` returns two values for many packages: I tried it for `libss-dev`, `firefox`, `bash`, and some more. For others, e.g. `less` or `sl` it returns only one value. For `libsslcommon2` `what-source` returns `qpid-cpp` only once. Maybe this is due to 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: @stackoverflowwww On my 15.04 system, `what-source libssl-dev` outputs only `openssl`, `what-source firefox` outputs only `firefox`, and `what-source bash` outputs only `bash`. What kind of output do you get from `what-source` when it shows two items?

Comment: simply two lines containing the name, see http://imgur.com/JzkleLh

Comment: Eliah wrote: "The reverse dependencies of a source package are not the same as the reverse build dependencies of a package. The reverse build dependencies of a package are the other packages that require the package in order to be built, but not necessarily to be installed once built."

Do I understand it correctly that I can find packages that statically link against, e.g. libssl, via `reverse-depends -b`? Packages that dynamically link against libssl via a `reverse-depends`?

Answer (score 3):

The `reverse-depends` software doesn't automatically detect the source package from which a given binary package is generated. The `src:` label is used to indicate that what follows is the name of a source package. It so happens that the name of the source package for `bash` is, well, `bash`. But for `libsslcommon2`, the source package is named [`qpid-cpp`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/qpid-cpp):

```
$ reverse-depends -r utopic src:qpid-cpp
Reverse-Depends
===============
* qpidd-msgstore                (for qpidd)
* qpidd-msgstore                (for libqpidbroker2)
* qpidd-msgstore                (for libqpidcommon2)

Packages without architectures listed are reverse-dependencies in: amd64, armhf, i386, ppc64el
```

`apt-get`, on the other hand, knows the source packages (check the output of `apt-cache show libsslcommon2`).

Comment: Why would anything depend on a source package anyway? Source code doesn't provide functionality. Or is there something that I'm missing?